# How implement line break for lists with sub-items ( Strapi cms )?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, rich-text-editor

I want fill content for terms and privacy page with strapi rich content editor, but it formatt my text wrong, instead line breaks for nested points 1.2, 1.2 etc I get text in 1 line.

**Example:**

**Editor**:
[image]

**Preview:**

[image]

**Example2**

**Mardown:**

[image]

**Preview:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this editor uses `markdown` syntax, you can get reference [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/markdown-cheat-sheet/)

the search terms `markdown` `mdx`

as for your question seems this is a regular problem with mdx, quick googling gave quite few of same issues

stack overflow also uses mdx, and seems you can use    (two empty spaces in the end of the line) tag:

1. Element 1
   1.1 Element 1.1
   1.2 Element 1.1
2. Element 2

```
1. Element 1  
1.1 Element 1.1  
1.2 Element 1.1
2. Element 2
```

the alternative method is to use `<br>`:

```
1. Element 1 <br>
1.1 Element 1.1 <br>
1.2 Element 1.1
2. Element 2
```

the [reference](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#line-break-best-practices)